# node js mysql rest api - queue http requests - persist data

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, task-queue

What is the best architectural design for following scenario?

I want to build a CRUD-microservice using node, express and mysql. The CREATE portion is quite complex due to a large piece of json with many relational properties on each http POST request. The `request.body` is looking something like this:

```
{
    key1: string <-- saved as foreign_key
    key2: {...}
    key3: int
    key4: [      <-- saved as n:m with corresponding table
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
    ...
    ...
    keyXYZ: ...
    key46: int   <-- saved as foreign_key
    key47: string
}
```

The module which does all query-operations looks like this:

```
persistData = async (data, dbConnection) => {
     const idSomething1 = await fetchOrCreateSomething1(data.key1).catch (err => console.log(err));
     const idSomething2 = await fetchOrCreateSomething2(data.key46).catch (err => console.log(err));
     const idSomething3 = await fetchOrCreateSomething3(data.keyXYZ).catch (err => console.log(err));
     const idManyThings = await fetchOrCreateManyThings(idSomething1, idSomething2,  idSomething3, data.moreStuff...).catch (err => console.log(err));
}
```

All `fetchOrCreateSomethingX = async () => {}` functions are async to let the main function `persistData` wait for an newly created or retrieved record id.

This is wrapped inside an exported constructor function:

```
function DataHandler(data, res) {
    db.getConnection()
        .then((dbConnection) => {
            persistData(data, dbConnection)
                .then(() => {
                    dbConnection.release();
                });
         });
}
module.exports = DataHandler;
```

The endpoint does the following:

```
const createFunc = (req, res) => {
    new DataHandler(req.body, res);
};
app.post("/create", createFunc);
```

I know that especially the last part does not work because the new DataHandler-object is overwritten as soon as the endpoint gets hit again. If the persisting process hasn't finished before the endpoint gets hit again the data from the first request is lost. I also know that express won't be able to send back responses which isn't ideal. If the new DataHandler instead would be stored to a new variable or const than at least both processes would run. But the main problem is that the data gets shuffled as the `persistData()` is running in parallel not encapsulated from each other.

I can't find any example or best practice how to design this well. Any hint or resource would be great!

Is a queuing system like the kue library the way to go?

Comment: I don't see why the object would get rewritten by concurrent requests. Also, if you return the promise from the `DataHandler` function, you could answer back to the user with something like this: `new DataHandler(req, res).then(() => res.send('Hooray!'))`

Comment: OK thanks! From a test script which just invokes `new DataHandler(req, res)` a few times my impression was like its behaving as described. Only the last invoking runs through. Anyhow. How can I make sure that one JSON object gets processed after another without hooking foreign key record ids from each other. Sorry for the unclear descriptions but I find it really hard to debug the process and see whats actually going on.

Comment: What puzzles me is why you're assigning a value to `req.body`, which is supposed to be filled by the http module with posted data (and, since it's scoped to each request, should not be destroyed until you stop using it).

Comment: Oh sorry. It was just to demonstrate whats in the body. I'm sending it by `axios.post(url, jsonObject)`. But - I think I have a solution to the "encapsulation"-problem: Could it be that you necessarily need to wrap each saving process inside a transaction like this `dbConnection.beginTransaction(function(err) { ...persistData(...)... });`?

Comment: Couldn't say without the whole code. But I think I see another possible issue: you're calling `persistData` with `(req, res, dbConnection)` while, according to your code, that function expects `(data, dbConnection)`, is this correct?

Comment: My bad. Changed it. Sorry again.